# Registering a type in QML using PySide2

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside2

I am trying to create a new QML type by using Python, but I am having trouble with registering a QML type. However, I am getting an Error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtQml.qmlRegisterType' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtQml.qmlRegisterType(module, str, int, int, str)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtQml.qmlRegisterType(type, str, int, int, str)
```

So I understand that its expecting a type, however, in this [blogpost](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/05/14/qml-qt-python/) it does something similar:

```
qmlRegisterType(PieChart, 'Charts', 1, 0, 'PieChart')
```

### Which leaves me confused, I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

In my main.py, I have this:

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare QApplication
    app=QApplication([])

    qmlRegisterType(CamFeed, 'CFeed', 1, 0, 'CamFeed')

    ...
```

CamFeed.py looks like this:

```
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickPaintedItem
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject

class CamFeed(QQuickPaintedItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    # Re-implementation of the virtual function
    def paint(self, painter):
        painter.drawRect(10,10,50,50)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely in the main.py file you are importing the CamFeed.py in the following way:

```
import CamFeed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare QApplication
    app = QApplication([])
    qmlRegisterType(CamFeed, 'CFeed', 1, 0, 'CamFeed')
```

In that case CamFeed is the module (.py file), so there are 2 solutions:

**1.**

```
from CamFeed import CamFeed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare QApplication
    app = QApplication([])
    qmlRegisterType(CamFeed, 'CFeed', 1, 0, 'CamFeed')
```

**2.**

```
import CamFeed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare QApplication
    app = QApplication([])
    qmlRegisterType(CamFeed.CamFeed, 'CFeed', 1, 0, 'CamFeed')
```

---

On the other hand by convention the name of the lowercase:

**camfeed.py**

```
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickPaintedItem
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject

class CamFeed(QQuickPaintedItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    # Re-implementation of the virtual function
    def paint(self, painter):
        painter.drawRect(10,10,50,50)
```

**main.py**

```
from camfeed import CamFeed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare QApplication
    app = QApplication([])
    qmlRegisterType(CamFeed, 'CFeed', 1, 0, 'CamFeed')
```

Comment: yes, it is class import related issue. Have to import types from another file properly.